# A incorporação de blocos em outros blocos não é suportada

Tags: herança, template, phalcon-php

Eu desenvolvi um template Volt e pretendo usá-lo como um padrão para os outros. Há um exemplo do meu código abaixo:

```
{# LOCKED MODE #}
{% if session.get('locked_mode', true) is not empty and session.get('locked_mode', true) is true %}
    {{ partial('locked_mode_view') }}
{# UNLOCKED MODE #}
{% else %}
<div class="row">
    {{ partial('unlocked_mode_view') }}

    {% block content %}
        {{ partial('unlocked_mode_content') }}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Enquanto ele estava compilando, o compilador mostrava esse erro:

```
Embedding blocks into other blocks is not supported in...
```

Eu não entendi esse erro. O que posso fazer nesta situação?